# Using an existing generic as an argument type in an extended function in Swift

Tags: swift

I am writing an extension for Measurement in Swift. I see in Apple's documentation that the Measurement is declared as `struct Measurement<UnitType> where UnitType : Unit`.

I want to use **UnitType** as the argument type for my extension's function.

```
    extension Measurement {
    
        func quotient(as otherUnit: UnitType) -> Measurement {
            return Measurement(value: floor(converted(to: otherUnit).value), unit: otherUnit)
        }
    
    }
```

This is an example of my function, but I am getting feedback saying...

> Referencing instance method 'converted(to:)' on 'Measurement' requires that 'UnitType' inherit from 'Dimension'

How can I utilize UnitType generic the Measurement instance is already using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic placeholder UnitType is defined as being some kind of Unit. But there are many kinds of Unit. As the documentation says, it is only Units that are Dimension subclasses that permit a Measurement to be `converted`:

> When a `Measurement` contains a `Dimension` unit, it gains the ability to convert between the kinds of units in that dimension.

So I would suggest you just do what the compiler says; reassure it that UnitType here does indeed inherit from Dimension:

```
extension Measurement where UnitType: Dimension {
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    func quotient(as otherUnit: UnitType) -> Measurement {
        return Measurement(value: floor(converted(to: otherUnit).value), unit: otherUnit)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing this does address the error. However, the generic already determined and used back in the original Measurement instance is lost. For example, `let m = Measurement(value: 3, unit: UnitLength.centimeters)` now knows the UnitType is UnitLength. Calling `m.converted(to: ___)` knows only to accept types of UnitLength. This behaviour is what I am hoping to achieve.

Comment: The following is now possible to write, for example, which is bizarre...
`Measurement(value: value, unit: UnitLength.centimeters).quotient(for: UnitArea.squareFeet)`

Comment: @Mathieson `extension Measurement where UnitType == UnitLength {`

Comment: Silly me, I thought the question was that you wanted your code to _compile_. You asked what you were doing wrong, that caused the compiler to give an error; I told you.

Comment: "How can I utilize UnitType generic the Measurement instance is already using?" You are utilizing it. The extension wouldn't be called if the UnitType were not eligible for conversion. The generic itself is still the generic.

Comment: I've changed that last line now. I can see how that may have played with the question of the context at the end. My bad! :P Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: @LeoDabus that will constrain it specifically to UnitLength, but again - I am hoping to leverage the UnitType that has already been determined for the instance of Measurement. This would not work if `let m = Measurement(value: 3, unit: UnitArea.sqareFeet)`, for example.

Comment: @matt I'm playing around in a playground now instead of in my code base, and it is behaving more as I'd expect here. I'm still wrapping my head around it a bit.

Comment: Yep, that does work. Bringing it to the playground helped isolate things and I now realize my confusion was coming from elsewhere. Thank you, @matt!